# Big-Theta(Θ) of the recursive function g(N) = (1/c)g(N/2)

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I'm trying to analyse the recursive function g(N) = (1/c)g(N/2), for N >= 2, with the terminating case being g(1) = 1, and then find the big-theta bounding it. Bare in mind, this problem treats n as if it were some power of 2, so N = 2<sup>n</sup> for example, which means n = lg(N).

What I found when doing this has me questioning whether or not I'm correct in my assumption. The i<sup>th</sup> case expands to g(N) = (c<sup>-i</sup>)g(2<sup>n - i</sup>). Then set n - i = 0, making  i = n and g(N) = (c<sup>-n</sup>)g(2<sup>n - n</sup>). Finally, g(2<sup>0</sup>) = 1, so g(N) = c<sup>-n</sup> = c<sup>-lg(N)</sup> = N <sup>-lg(c)</sup> = (1/N)<sup>lg(c)</sup>

What I gather out of this is that (1/N)<sup>p</sup> = Θ(0), since the limit of (1/N)<sup>p</sup> as N -> ∞ is equal to 0.

I'm really just wondering if I'm doing this right, since in real world applications I wouldn't think it's possible to have an algorithm with a time complexity of 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write

> real world applications... algorithm with a time complexity...

so it seems that the recurrence *g(n) = (1/c)g(n/2)* stands for the running time of a real-world algorithm. As such, this makes sense only if *0 < c < 1*, since, otherwise, it's an algorithm that works faster on larger inputs, which doesn't make much sense in the real world.

Your analysis makes sense, up to the point where you analyze *Θ(<sup>-lg(c)</sup>)*, and decide this tends to 0. For the reasonable values of *c*, it naturally enough tends to infinity.

Comment: This will have to be something that I ask my instructor then, because the assignment does not place bounds on the constant _c_, only on the values of N, which must be >= 2.

I see what you are saying though, as `-lg(c)` for `0 < c < 1` would tend to infinity.